# Does mysqli have support for ms sql?

Tags: php, mysqli

Does mysqli have support for MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

I quote:

> The mysqli extension allows you to access the functionality provided by MySQL 4.1 and above. More information about the MySQL Database server can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/

So probably no :)